# Jquery get value (not selected) from select using text

Tags: jquery

How to get the value of select list (not selected) using the text. I have used filter function but same is not working

```
var value1 = $('#ddldept option').filter(function() { 
    return $(this).text() === 'abc';
}).val();
```

value1 is coming undefined..

Comment: i tried with .attr('value') still it is undefined

Comment: @sergioramosiker:can you share the fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the values which is not selected, then

```
var value1 = $('#ddldept option').not(':selected').filter(function () {
    return $(this).text() === 'abc';
}).val();

console.log(value1);
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/nR7j7/4/)